# Finding the count of authors

Tags: sql

There are two tables: `authors(authorid, name)` and `books(bookid, authorid, title, year)`.

What sql query could I write to count how many books authors have in books table and if some author has none it would return zero?

I have tried:

```
Select authors.name, count(authors.authorid) as count
FROM authors, books
where authors.authorid = books.authorid
group by authors.authorid;
```

Example output:

```
name count
author1 1
author2 0
```

Comment: Use modern `JOIN` syntax, available since 1999.

Answer (score 0):

use left join and modern join not coma separated join

```
Select authors.name, count(books.authorid)
FROM authors left join books
on authors.authorid = books.authorid
 group by authors.name
```